# Not able to login into SQL Server 2012 installed with an EC2 instance of type m4.xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

i have created an EC2 instance 'm4.xlarge' type which have SQL Server 2012 installed on it.
But i am not able to login into SQL Server, is there any default password for that.
i have tried Windows authentication but it failed.

Comment: No need of password in Windows form authentication if you are using RDC of the instance

Comment: What AMI did you use to launch the instance? Only Amazon Windows AMIs or custom AMIs with the Ec2SetPassword setting enabled in the Config.xml file will generate a password. Instances launched from a custom AMI without this setting use the username and password of the AMI's parent instance.